# Data splitting with caret: Can we remove the ID Coloumn after folds are created?

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret

so we have a dependent sample (two observations for each participant). To prevent data from one participant being in the training set and in the unseen fold in cross-validation we used the groupKFold method from the `caret` R-Package. I was wondering if it is correct that I remove the ID column after the folds are created and before the training it self.

```
  ############## Caret Preparation ############## 
  set.seed(77)
  k.folds = 5
  dataframe.folds <- groupKFold(group = dataframe$id, k = k.folds) 
  dataframe.control <- trainControl( # k Folds grouped by subject cross validation, repeated 3 times
    method = "repeatedcv", 
    number = k.folds, 
    repeats = 3,
    index = dataframe.folds,
    savePredictions = T,
    summaryFunction = allSummary,
    classProbs = T
    )

  dataframe <- select(dataframe, -"id")
  dataframe.tunegrid <- expand.grid(.size=c(1:(ncol(dataframe)-1)))


  mlp <- train(Class~., 
               data=dataframe, 
               method="mlp", 
               metric="Accuracy", 
               tuneGrid=dataframe.tunegrid, 
               trControl=dataframe.control
               # , preProc=c("center", "scale","zv")
               )
```

Comment: I meanwhile found out that you can just easily exclude the ID Column by calling train with `train(Class~.-ID, ...)`. [See also this really helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5251676/7318488) Additionally the groupKfolds works with the IDs of the rows rather than the values of the ID column, so it should be save to remove the ID column, after groupKfolds is called